# where are rails inbuilt and default method written in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can any one explain help me understand how to find the location and definition or errors such as "NoMethodError" in rails app.

Please let me know where can I get all the rails inbuilt method and function list.

Comment: Here are all rails methods: https://github.com/rails/rails/

Comment: @SergioTulentsev please help me by letting me know where is the inbuilt method written in rails app. this would be very helpful to me.

Comment: I think you got cleared with this, so try looking for _'how to override method_missing to avoid NomethodError in rails'_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoMethodError` is a core error in ruby.  Normally your best best is to go [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0) for ruby docs and check or [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/) for rails

NoMethodError lives [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/NoMethodError.html) in the ruby docs

Comment: Thanks, Can you please suggest me  some book or study material to brushup my rails basic.

Comment: Absolutely, https://www.railstutorial.org/ and https://rubymonk.com/ are both free.  Good luck, please reach out if you need more.